# OneR WEKA - wrong prediction?

Tags: classification, weka

I am trying to make a ranking of attributes depending on their predictive power by using OneR in WEKA iteratively. At every run I remove the chosen attribute to see what the next best is.

I have done this for all my attributes and some (3 out of ten attributes) get 'ranked' higher than others, although they have less % correct prediction, a smaller ROC Area average and their rules are less compact.

As I understand, OneR just looks at the frequency tables for the attribute it has and then the class values, so it wouldn't care about whether I take attributes out or not...but I am probably missing something

Would anyone have an idea?

Comment: To speed this up, you can use the "Select Attributes" menu, and then the OneRAttributeEval Method. The results can vary depending on whether you choose "Use full training set" or "Cross-Validation". What did you use (in Classify menu, presumably), cross-valiidation or full-training-set?

Comment: Thanks for this, I did end up using OneRAttributeEval - and then the results were just fine. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you can you use the OneR package (available on CRAN, more information here: [OneR - Establishing a New Baseline for Machine Learning Classification Models](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OneR/vignettes/OneR.html))

With the option `verbose = TRUE` you get the accuracy of all attributes, e.g.:

```
> library(OneR)
> example(OneR)

OneR> data <- optbin(iris)

OneR> model <- OneR(data, verbose = TRUE)

    Attribute    Accuracy
1 * Petal.Width  96%     
2   Petal.Length 95.33%  
3   Sepal.Length 74.67%  
4   Sepal.Width  55.33%  
---
Chosen attribute due to accuracy
and ties method (if applicable): '*'


OneR> summary(model)

Rules:
If Petal.Width = (0.0976,0.791] then Species = setosa
If Petal.Width = (0.791,1.63]   then Species = versicolor
If Petal.Width = (1.63,2.5]     then Species = virginica

Accuracy:
144 of 150 instances classified correctly (96%)

Contingency table:
            Petal.Width
Species      (0.0976,0.791] (0.791,1.63] (1.63,2.5] Sum
  setosa               * 50            0          0  50
  versicolor              0         * 48          2  50
  virginica               0            4       * 46  50
  Sum                    50           52         48 150
---
Maximum in each column: '*'

Pearson's Chi-squared test:
X-squared = 266.35, df = 4, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

(full disclosure: I am the author of this package and I would be very interested in the results you get)

Answer (score 0):

The OneR classifier looks a bit like nearest-neighbor. Given that, the following applies: In the [source code of the OneR classifier](https://github.com/bnjmn/weka/blob/0aa313304b68cbde7bd0045653c3f548fb7f430a/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/rules/OneR.java), it says:

```
    // if this attribute is the best so far, replace the rule
    if (noRule || r.m_correct > m_rule.m_correct) {
      m_rule = r;
    }
```

Thus, it should be possible (either in [1-R generally](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/Publications/simple_rules.pdf) or in this implementation) for an attribute to block another, yet be later removed in your process.

Say you have attributes 1,2, and 3 with the distribution 1: 50%, 2: 30%, 3: 20%. In all cases where attribute 1 is best, attribute 3 is second best.

Thus, when attribute 1 is left out, attribute 3 wins with 70%, even though before attribute 2 ranked as "better" than 3 in the comparison of all three.